# Why the click event will not working in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html and jQuery code in which there are two `img` dynamically created and after ajax I'm applying click events on the images but the click events not working. Means they show nothing. that the imae is clicked or not. I'm showing my code following:-

```
<div id="images">
     <img id="image/5c07a4337c76881db6bf9a7f" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA.....>
     <img id="image/5c07a4337c76881db6bf9a7d" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA.....>
</div>


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1/get-all-upload-image?sortBy=date",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $.ajax({
                url : "/api/v1/base-strings",
                type:"GET",
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response.response.data)
                    for (i= 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++){
                        console.log(response.response.data[i])
                        var base64_string = response.response.data[i].data;
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.setAttribute("id", "image/"+response.response.data[i].files_id);
                         img.setAttribute("onclick", "addListeners()");
                        // added `width` , `height` properties to `img` attributes
                        img.style.width ='340px';
                        img.style.height ='194px';
                        img.style.margin = '50px';
                        img.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                        img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64_string;
                        var preview = document.getElementById("images");
                        preview.appendChild(img);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    function addListeners () {
        $('img[id^="image"]').on('click', function(){
          var val = $(this).attr('id').split('/');
          id= val[val.length - 1] 
        });
    }
    $('img[id^="image"]').click(function(){
        alert("hello")
    })
    $('img[id^="image"]').on('click', function(){
                        var val = $(this).attr('id').split('/');
                        id= val[val.length - 1] 
                    });
});
```

Error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addListeners is not defined
>       at HTMLImageElement.onclick

What is the problem with the code why it is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: there is always a problem in click event on images, I faced the same problem 2 days ago, Just change image tag into div and instead of src use style and background-image

Answer (score 0):

Listen Just do it like I said. Paste the below code after your first ajax call:-

```
 $('body').on('click','img', function(){
         alert("I'm here");
  });
```

Hope Works well :)